# Am I correctly interpreting these two fundamental equations about capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, theory

Capacitors follow the fundamental equation \$I(t)=CV'(t)\$, from which we can derive
$$Q'(t) = CV'(t).$$
Recently, I read about [the equation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capchg.html) that describes the charging of a capacitor:
$$Q(t) = CV(t)\left(1-e^{-t/\text{RC}}\right).$$

---

I wish to make sure of small thing: the \$Q\$ (or \$V\$) in each equation **means a different thing**, right?

For example, the \$Q\$ in the first equation refers to the amount of charge flowing *through* the capacitor at any given time, while the \$Q\$ in the second equation refers to the charge *stored* in the capacitor's plates.

Similarly, the \$V\$ in the first equation refers to the voltage drop *across* the capacitor, while the \$V\$ in the second equation refers to the voltage difference between points \$A\$ and \$B\$ in a circuit such as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQFKqb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As a consequence, we may not substitute the \$Q\$ (or \$V\$) of one equation with the \$Q\$ (or \$V\$) of the other.

---

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes Q and V are the same, but obviously you cannot substitute a quantity with its d/dt'ed form

Answer (score 0):

> For example, the Q
> in the first equation refers to the amount of charge flowing through the capacitor at any given time, ...

No, \$ Q \$ is the charge on (or stored in) the capacitor in both equations.

The important thing to notice is that the first equation is for \$ Q'(t)\$ which is the derivative of \$Q\$ with respect to time = the rate of change of charge = the current in or out of \$ C \$.

In more conventional notation we can write the first equation as
$$ I = \frac {dQ}{dt} = C\frac {dV}{dt} $$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in the first equation, there is \$Q'\$ instead of just \$Q\$ (the apostrophe behind the letter Q and also V).
\$Q'\$ means a time-derivative of \$Q\$.

So, yes, it describes how Q and V are changing, not their current value.

Comment: yes, but beyond that, does the \$Q\$ in the first equation equal the \$Q\$ in the second? That is, could we differentiate the second equation and equate both \$Q'\$s?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. In the first equation, Q refers to the instantaneous charge flowing through the capacitor, and V represents the voltage drop across it. In the second equation, Q refers to the accumulated charge stored in the capacitor over time, and V represents the voltage across the capacitor plates.

For practical circuit analysis and troubleshooting, you can use multimeters. Some advanced multimeters can [measure the capacitance of capacitors](https://www.jakelectronics.com/blog/what-is-the-symbol-for-microfarads-on-a-multimeter).